# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 query = "select StudentName,FatherName,ContactNo from Student  where Class='" 
           + cmbClass.Text == null ? "" : cmbClass.Text.Trim() + " and isActive=1 '";    
 }
 else if (!cmbSection.Text.Contains("Select"))
 {
   query += " and Section='" + cmbSection.Text == null ? "" 
                                                       : cmbSection.Text.Trim() + "' ";
 }
```

Comment: `"' and isActive=1 "`

Comment: "' and isActive=1 "
You need to close single quote

Comment: Just to start you should be building your query with SqlCommand not just a plain string. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: after the changing iam facing this exception Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' and isActive=1 '.

Comment: As stated by CubicleJockey, your method of querying your database leaves you open to attacks via SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

You opened a single quote for Class=' but then put isActive=1 before you closed the other single quote. Move ' from right of isActive=1 to in front of it like below.

**Below C# 6 version:**

```
if(/*your clause*/) 
{
  query = string.Format("SELECT StudentName, FatherName, ContactNo FROM Student WHERE Class='{0}' AND isActive = 1", cmbClass.Text == null ? string.Empty : cmbClass.Text.Trim()) //<-- you quote was meant for Class but was on wrong side of isActive
} 

if (!cmbSection.Text.Contains("SELECT")) //<--- else probably shouldn't be there or you will never hit this clause after going in the above if
{
  query += string.Format(" AND Section='{0}' ", cmbSection.Text == null ? string.Empty : cmbSection.Text.Trim())
}
```

**C# 6 version:**

```
if (/*your clause*/)
{
    var classText = cmbClass.Text == null ? string.Empty : cmbClass.Text.Trim()
    query = $"SELECT StudentName, FatherName, ContactNo FROM Student WHERE Class='{classText}' AND isActive = 1", ) //<-- you quote was meant for Class but was on wrong side of isActive
} 

if (!cmbSection.Text.Contains("SELECT"))
{
   var section = cmbSection.Text == null ? string.Empty : cmbSection.Text.Trim();
   query += $" AND Section='{section}'";
}
```

Also you shouldn't be building your queries this way it's bad practice. You should get familiar with [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) and it's related SqlClient.

Comment: still facing same problem Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' and isActive=1'

Comment: This is in an else/if block what are your other if statements doing?

Comment: its like that if (){query = 
"SELECT StudentName, FatherName, ContactNo FROM Student WHERE Class='" 
        + cmbClass.Text == null ? string.Empty : cmbClass.Text.Trim() 
        + "' AND isActive=1"; //<-- you quote was meant for Class but was on wrong side of isActive
} 
else if (!cmbSection.Text.Contains("Select")) 
{
    query += " AND Section='" 
             + cmbSection.Text == null ? string.Empty 
                                       : cmbSection.Text.Trim() + "' ";

Comment: Updated the answer. With Below C# 6 and C# 6 version try that. The string format or interpolation make it clear where the single quotes go.

Comment: Okay well then use the top answer but C# 6 is still in the answer for others to look at and for you to learn string interpolation.

Comment: now its a default and showing the iso-1 ,iso2 and C# 3.0